# Get specific value from array object in a single line in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a following array

```
const _array = [{id: 1, name: 'Adam'}, {id:3, name: 'Crystal'}, {id:2, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 4, name: 'Daisy'}];
```

How to write a single line of code in typescript to get item where name equal to Crystal from the array?

Comment: Please stop for a moment and reflect on why are you getting a little bit of negative votes. Hint: answer for this question can be easily googled. Please take your time goggling for even just a bit before asking questions here.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Don't know man! any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array find method like following:

```
const _array = [
  { id: 1, name: "Adam" },
  { id: 3, name: "Crystal" },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob" },
  { id: 4, name: "Daisy" },
];

const item = _array.find((item) => item.name === "Crystal");

console.log(item);
```

**Output**

```
{ id: 3, name: 'Crystal' }
```